# The debugger is not hitting the break-points

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, rust, visual-studio-2022

I have installed [Visual Studio 2022 Community](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/) edition and also the [Rust Analyzer for VS2022](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kitamstudios.RustAnalyzer).

I can clean and build Rust packages. However, I am facing a problem with debugging.

I can set a break-point but I can't debug the code as the debugger is not hitting the break-points.

[image]

**Note:** I am not doing unit tests. I am just trying to debug `main()`.

**How can I resolve this issue?**

---

The following is my Rust project information under ***Visual Studio 2022***:

[image]

**`Cargo.toml`**:

```
[workspace]


[package]
name = "my_rust_workspace"
version = "4.0.0-dev"
edition = "2021"
description = "Provides the package"
license = "Apache-2.0"

[dependencies]


[[bin]]
name = "main_executable"
path = "./main.rs"
```

**`main.rs`**:

```
fn main() {
    
    let c1 = 5;
    let c2 = 10;

    let _c3 = c1 + c2;
    let _c4 = 200;
}
```

**tasks.js.jason**

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "cargo build",
      "dependsOn": [
        "cargo build example"
      ]
    },
    {
      "label": "cargo build release",
      "dependsOn": [
        "cargo build example release"
      ]
    },
    {
      "label": "cargo build example",
      "type": "cargo",
      "command": "build",
      "args": [],
      "problemMatcher": [
        "$rustc"
      ],
      "options": {
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
      }
    },
    {
      "label": "cargo build example release",
      "type": "cargo",
      "command": "build",
      "args": [
        "--release"
      ],
      "problemMatcher": [
        "$rustc"
      ],
      "options": {
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "cargo",
      "command": "build",
      "problemMatcher": [
        "$rustc"
      ],
      "group": "build",
      "label": "rust: cargo build"
    },
    {
      "taskLabel": "task-Rust - vs2022 debug",
      "appliesTo": "/",
      "type": "launch"
    }
  ]
}
```

**launch.vs.json**

```
{
  "version": "0.2.1",
  "defaults": {},
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "native",
      "name": "C:\\git\\___Rust_vs2022",
      "project": "",
      "projectTarget": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

The following is my **symbols** setting:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue.

**Step 1.** Set both Visual Studio 2022 and Rust-compatible toolchain as the default.

```
C:\Users\pc>rustup toolchain list
stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu
nightly-2018-12-06-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc (default)

C:\Users\pc>
```

In my case, it was `nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc`.

`nightly-2018-12-06-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc` was not Rust compatible. I tested it and it generated hundreds of weird errors.

**Step 2.** Remove any `[profile.XYZ]` sections from the `Cargo.toml` file.

Those are `[profile.bench]`, `[profile.debug]`, `[profile.dev]`, `[profile.release]`, `[profile.test]`, etc.

**Step 3.** Set `Cargo.toml` as the startup file.

Then, the build and debug buttons will be visible, and we can press them to build and debug the project.